# Replace ID variable values with counts of value occurrences

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame like:

```
      DATE    x       y    ID
06/10/2003  7.21    0.651   1
12/10/2003  5.99    0.428   1
18/10/2003  4.68    1.04    1
24/10/2003  3.47    0.363   1
30/10/2003  2.42    0.507   1
02/05/2010  2.72    0.47    2
05/05/2010  2.6 0.  646     2
08/05/2010  2.67    0.205   2
11/05/2010  3.57    0.524   2
12/05/2010  0.428   4.68    3
13/05/2010  1.04    3.47    3
14/05/2010  0.363   2.42    3
18/10/2003  0.507   2.52    3
24/10/2003  0.418   4.68    3
30/10/2003  0.47    3.47    3
29/04/2010  0.646   2.42    4
18/10/2003  3.47    2.52    4
```

i have the count of number of rows per group for column ID as an integer vector like 5 4 6 2

is there a way to replace the group values in column id with these integer vector 5 4 6 2

the output i am expecting is

```
DATE    x   y   ID
06/10/2003  7.21    0.651   5
12/10/2003  5.99    0.428   5
18/10/2003  4.68    1.04    5
24/10/2003  3.47    0.363   5
30/10/2003  2.42    0.507   5
02/05/2010  2.72    0.47    4
05/05/2010  2.6      646    4
08/05/2010  2.67    0.205   4
11/05/2010  3.57    0.524   4
12/05/2010  0.428   4.68    6
13/05/2010  1.04    3.47    6
14/05/2010  0.363   2.42    6
18/10/2003  0.507   2.52    6
24/10/2003  0.418   4.68    6
30/10/2003  0.47    3.47    6
29/04/2010  0.646   2.42    2
18/10/2003  3.47    2.52    2
```

i am quite new to R and tried to find if there is any idea replace function. But having a hard time. Any help is much appreciated.

above data is just an example for understanding my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ID = ID2) %>%
  select(-ID2)
```

**Edit:**

I've just found a solution that's a bit cleaner than the above:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID2 = ID) %>%
  mutate(ID = n()) %>%
  select(-ID2)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 17 x 4
         DATE     x     y    ID
       <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 06/10/2003 7.210 0.651     5
 2 12/10/2003 5.990 0.428     5
 3 18/10/2003 4.680 1.040     5
 4 24/10/2003 3.470 0.363     5
 5 30/10/2003 2.420 0.507     5
 6 02/05/2010 2.720 0.470     4
 7 05/05/2010 2.600 0.646     4
 8 08/05/2010 2.670 0.205     4
 9 11/05/2010 3.570 0.524     4
10 12/05/2010 0.428 4.680     6
11 13/05/2010 1.040 3.470     6
12 14/05/2010 0.363 2.420     6
13 18/10/2003 0.507 2.520     6
14 24/10/2003 0.418 4.680     6
15 30/10/2003 0.470 3.470     6
16 29/04/2010 0.646 2.420     2
17 18/10/2003 3.470 2.520     2
```

**Notes:**

The reason behind `ungroup() %>% mutate(ID = ID2) %>% select(-ID2)` is that `dplyr` doesn't allow `mutate`ing on grouping variables. So this would not work:

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(ID = n())
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `ID` can't be modified
>   because it's a grouping variable

If you don't care about replacing the original `ID` column, you can just do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = n())
```

**Alternative Result:**

```
# A tibble: 17 x 5
# Groups:   ID [4]
         DATE     x     y    ID   ID2
       <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 06/10/2003 7.210 0.651     1     5
 2 12/10/2003 5.990 0.428     1     5
 3 18/10/2003 4.680 1.040     1     5
 4 24/10/2003 3.470 0.363     1     5
 5 30/10/2003 2.420 0.507     1     5
 6 02/05/2010 2.720 0.470     2     4
 7 05/05/2010 2.600 0.646     2     4
 8 08/05/2010 2.670 0.205     2     4
 9 11/05/2010 3.570 0.524     2     4
10 12/05/2010 0.428 4.680     3     6
11 13/05/2010 1.040 3.470     3     6
12 14/05/2010 0.363 2.420     3     6
13 18/10/2003 0.507 2.520     3     6
14 24/10/2003 0.418 4.680     3     6
15 30/10/2003 0.470 3.470     3     6
16 29/04/2010 0.646 2.420     4     2
17 18/10/2003 3.470 2.520     4     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ave()` function to calculate how many rows each ID takes up. In the example below I created a new variable `ID2`, but you could replace the original ID if you want.

(I included code to create your data in R below, but when you ask questions in the future please include your data in the question by using the `dput()` function on the data object. That's what I did to make the code below.)

```
mydata <- structure(list(DATE = c("06/10/2003", "12/10/2003", "18/10/2003", 
                        "24/10/2003", "30/10/2003", "02/05/2010", "05/05/2010", "08/05/2010", 
                        "11/05/2010", "12/05/2010", "13/05/2010", "14/05/2010", "18/10/2003", 
                        "24/10/2003", "30/10/2003", "29/04/2010", "18/10/2003"), 
                   x = c(7.21, 5.99, 4.68, 3.47, 2.42, 2.72, 2.6, 2.67, 3.57, 0.428, 1.04, 0.363, 
                         0.507, 0.418, 0.47, 0.646, 3.47), 
                   y = c(0.651, 0.428, 1.04, 0.363, 0.507, 0.47, 646, 0.205, 0.524, 4.68, 3.47, 
                         2.42, 2.52, 4.68, 3.47, 2.42, 2.52), 
             ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)), 
             .Names = c("DATE", "x", "y", "ID"), 
             class = c("data.frame"), 
             row.names = c(NA, -17L))

# ave() takes an input object, an object of group IDs of the same length 
#   as the input object, and a function to apply to the input object split across groups         
mydata$ID2 <- ave(mydata$ID, mydata$ID, FUN = length)

mydata

   DATE       x       y     ID ID2
1  06/10/2003 7.210   0.651  1   5
2  12/10/2003 5.990   0.428  1   5
3  18/10/2003 4.680   1.040  1   5
4  24/10/2003 3.470   0.363  1   5
5  30/10/2003 2.420   0.507  1   5
6  02/05/2010 2.720   0.470  2   4
7  05/05/2010 2.600 646.000  2   4
8  08/05/2010 2.670   0.205  2   4
9  11/05/2010 3.570   0.524  2   4
10 12/05/2010 0.428   4.680  3   6
11 13/05/2010 1.040   3.470  3   6
12 14/05/2010 0.363   2.420  3   6
13 18/10/2003 0.507   2.520  3   6
14 24/10/2003 0.418   4.680  3   6
15 30/10/2003 0.470   3.470  3   6
16 29/04/2010 0.646   2.420  4   2
17 18/10/2003 3.470   2.520  4   2

# if you want to replace the original ID variable, you can assign to it 
#   instead of adding a new variable
mydata$ID <- ave(mydata$ID, mydata$ID, FUN = length)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. tested the result. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A compact solution with the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, ID := .N, by = ID][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > mydf
>           DATE     x     y ID
>  1: 06/10/2003 7.210 0.651  5
>  2: 12/10/2003 5.990 0.428  5
>  3: 18/10/2003 4.680 1.040  5
>  4: 24/10/2003 3.470 0.363  5
>  5: 30/10/2003 2.420 0.507  5
>  6: 02/05/2010 2.720 0.470  4
>  7: 05/05/2010 2.600 0.646  4
>  8: 08/05/2010 2.670 0.205  4
>  9: 11/05/2010 3.570 0.524  4
> 10: 12/05/2010 0.428 4.680  6
> 11: 13/05/2010 1.040 3.470  6
> 12: 14/05/2010 0.363 2.420  6
> 13: 18/10/2003 0.507 2.520  6
> 14: 24/10/2003 0.418 4.680  6
> 15: 30/10/2003 0.470 3.470  6
> 16: 29/04/2010 0.646 2.420  2
> 17: 18/10/2003 3.470 2.520  2
> ```

What this does:

- `setDT(mydf)` converts the dataframe to a *data.table*
- `by = ID` groups by `ID`
- `ID := .N` replaces the original value of `ID` with the count by group